# filter images from another webpage using fetch

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, fetch-api

I am trying to make a cross website cart application where users would input a link and using fetch  the website would get the title image and price of the product. the price and title are working fine but I am having trouble filtering the image. The way I find the product image is by looking for the largest one but even though I can get the tag for the images I cant retrieve any styling info on them. please help.

here is my current code (in order to get around the CORS stuff I downloaded the cors unblock extension)

```
fetch('https://www.quince.com/men/men-s-100-linen-longsleeve-shirt?color=black')
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(data => {
    // Step 2: Parse HTML Data
    const parser = new DOMParser();
    const htmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(data, 'text/html');

    // Step 3: Extract Information
    var name = htmlDoc.querySelectorAll("h1")[0].innerText;
    name = name.replace(".","")
    

// Find the div with the specified class
    const productImageDiv = htmlDoc.querySelector('.product-image.product-image-react');
let images;

if (productImageDiv) {
  images = productImageDiv.getElementsByTagName('img');
} else {
  images = htmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('img');
}

let largestImage = null;
let largestSize = 0;
console.log(images[0])
// Loop through the images and find the largest one
// Inside the loop for image retrieval
for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    const image = images[i];
    console.log(image)
    // Check if the image has loaded
    if (image.complete) {
      const imageSize = image.width * image.height;
      
      if (imageSize > largestSize) {
        largestSize = imageSize;
        largestImage = image;
      }
    } else {
      // If the image hasn't loaded yet, listen for the 'load' event
      image.addEventListener('load', function () {
        const imageSize = image.width * image.height;
        
        if (imageSize > largestSize) {
          largestSize = imageSize;
          largestImage = image;
          console.log(image)
        }
      });
    }
  }
  

    // Step 4: Handle CORS and Same-Origin Policy
    // You might need to use a server-side proxy or other methods to overcome CORS restrictions.

    // Step 5: Display Information
    console.log(name);
    console.log(extractedNumber)
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The `width` and `height` properties of an image are only populated if they're set in HTML (eg. `<img width='1920' ...>`). It looks like the site you're checking images on doesn't have those properties set on most of its images.

There might be two different things you want:

If you want to get the actual width and height of the element on the page, that's actually quite easy! You can use [Element.getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect), which will return an object including a width and height. This is what the code for that might look like:

```js
const rect = image.getBoundingClientRect()
// Now you can access rect.width and rect.height
```

Here's what it looks like with me testing that function out myself on your page:

[image]

If you want to get the width and height of the image file itself — for example, as encoded in PNG metadata — that's a decent amount harder. You would have to fetch the image URL yourself and, through some means, calculate the width and height.